# How to change a value in a response?

Tags: python-3.x

```
[def duckFeet():

    print ("What is an average duck’s shoe size?")

    shoe_size=input()

    print (shoe_size + "? How do you know?")

    answer = input()

    print(answer + "? Ineresting!")

duckFeet()
```

when I run and answer I get this on the console

```
What is an average duck’s shoe size?
 6
6? How do you know?
I know
I know? Ineresting!
```

I want it to be able to make it to where if you answer with an I or am it will be changed to you or are on the console. Can anyone help me?][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbWXa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use [str.replace(old, new)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for "I" and "am":

```
newanswer = answer.replace("I", "You").replace("am", "are")
print(newanswer + "? Ineresting!")
```

Demo:

```
What is an average duck's shoe size?
6
6? How do you know?
I know
You know? Ineresting!
```

Or:

```
What is an average duck's shoe size?
6
6? How do you know?
I am all-knowing
You are all-knowing? Ineresting!
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful.